# do shortcode not working for Advanced post slider

Tags: wordpress

I've been stuck on this for a while. I'm working on a wordpress site.

I'm trying to use a Advanced post slider plugin, but calling it in a template via

```
echo do_shortcode('[advps-slideshow optset="1"]'); //just isn't working.
```

But it is working when directly pasted `[advps-slideshow optset="1"]` in wordpress page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Advanced post slider looks to be working my end with the code you provided. What happens if you do `<?php print_r(do_shortcode('[advps-slideshow optset="1"]')); ?>` are you also getting any js errors in your console log?

Answer (score 0):

the problem seems to be in the plugin itself, as I see no errors in the string you wrote. I think you should write the developers with this issue. you may suggest you another slider plugin with shortcodes for WP post galleries- freemake slider. on you blog it works well. the archive can be loaded from here http://www.freemake.com/free_wordpress_slider_plugin/